# How to convert .xcodeproj to .cpp

Tags: c++, xcode

To submit a homework assignment, I must submit a .cpp file but Xcode automatically saves it as a .xcodeproj file. How can I convert this to .cpp?

Answer (score 1):

Xcode opens an Xcode project (an .xcodeproj) file by default.

And inside that project you'll find your .cpp file which you can turn into your teachers.

If you look on the left side of the Xcode project window, you'll see a list of folders and files, and you should see your .cpp file in there.

When you hold down the control key while mouse clicking on that file, you'll see a menu pop up where one of the choices is "Show in Finder".  Choose THAT, and you'll see where your .cpp file is.

[image: How To Get to Your CPP file]

Answer (score 0):

Either you can submit the whole project folder or just *.cpp and *.h files of your project if there is no requirement for using any specific IDE for homework or details of how to submit them. For example, some professors ask students to add `Make` files in their submisions